# Installing DSE on Amazon EC2 m4.* instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

I would like to install DSE on m4.* instances, but it seems that the latest [ComboAMI](https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI) doesn't support it. Since it requires a different configuration, as it's not an instance-store backed instance, but rather an ebs-store backed instance and also a HVM instance and not PV instance.

I've started working on a new provisioning script, that basically does what the ComboAMI provisioning script does, but also adds the RAID0 creation for the EBS volumes that I attach per node, and the xfs file system creation.

My question is divided to two parts:
First of all, I was wondering if anyone in DataStax has already done something similar that he can share, since that can be a great reference for anyone that wants to do something similar.

Second of all, has anyone had any experience building a similar AMI on a m4.* instance type? I didn't manage to get something to work with the ComboAMI project.

Comment: Did you look at all the available AMIs in the ComboAMI `ami_ids.json` file?  There are hvm versions listed: https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI/blob/2.6/ami_ids.json

Comment: Yeah but I still can't select a m4.* instance when trying to install with one of those AMIs